# Full height element - MiGLayout

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I have the below image. It consists of a JPanel containing one label for the picture, another one for the '@usuario1' text, another one for 'contenido', and another one for '#demo'. Below the image is the code which constructs it.

[image: src]

```
SettingsManagerTab.panelForTweet1 = new JPanel();
SettingsManagerTab.panelForTweet1.setOpaque(true);
SettingsManagerTab.panelForTweet1.setLayout(new net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout());
this.add(SettingsManagerTab.panelForTweet1);

SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetPhoto1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
        SettingsManagerTab.class.getResource("/res/User1.png")));
SettingsManagerTab.panelForTweet1.add(SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetPhoto1);

SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetUsername1 = new JLabel("@usuario1");
final Font contentFont = new Font(SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetUsername1.getFont()
        .getName(), Font.BOLD, SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetUsername1.getFont()
        .getSize());
final Font userFont = new Font(contentFont.getName(), Font.BOLD,
        (int) (contentFont.getSize() * 0.7));
SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetUsername1.setFont(userFont);
SettingsManagerTab.panelForTweet1.add(SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetUsername1);

SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetContent1 = new JLabel("contenido");
SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetContent1.setFont(contentFont);
SettingsManagerTab.panelForTweet1.add(SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetContent1);

SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetHashtag1 = new JLabel("#demo");
SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetHashtag1.setFont(contentFont);
SettingsManagerTab.panelForTweet1.add(SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetHashtag1);
```

But what I want to achieve is this:

[image: goal]

It looked trivial to me. Simply make *growy* the label with the picture, and then add the '@usuario1' with *wrap* option so the next component (the 'contenido' label) is added at the beginning of the next line and, since the picture label is occupying all the height of the JPanel, the mentioned next line will start just below the '@usuario1' label. However what seems to happen is that the next line starts just below the picture label, but since the label is taking all the height of the JPanel, it isn't shown, so I get a result which is worse than the beginning.

Is my goal possible? And if so, how?

Comment: Sure that's possible :-) Please show a SSCCE to demonstrate what you want to achieve vs. what happens so we can tweak that to show you how-to exactly reach your goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go through PDF present at [link](http://www.miglayout.com/) for MiGLayout or you can try GridBagLayout. If you want to use GridBagLayout  [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) might be helpful. Using GridBagLayout you can set the component as you want.


Take reference of below example:

```
    panel.add(comp1);
    panel.add(comp2, "span 2 2"); // The component will span 2x2 cells.
    panel.add(comp3, "wrap"); // Wrap to next row
    panel.add(comp4);
    panel.add(comp5, "wrap"); // Note that it "jumps over" the occupied cells.
    panel.add(comp6);
    panel.add(comp7);
```

O/p:

[image]

Comment: Obviously I read the cheat sheet (otherwise how am I supposed to know about the growy and wrap options?). And for GridBagLayout, of course I'd prefer using a JDK layout rather than an outer one, but if I'm trying with MiGLayout, it's because I'm not very skilled with layouts, but MiGLayout is (or it should, at least) fairly easy to use, but offers many possibilities that in fact I'm already using in  other places in my application (that's why, althought I'd prefer to use an original layout, I don't really mind that much using MiGLayout).

Comment: Updated my Answer. You will get some idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

Haha! Managed to do it thanks to your indications sachin, but with GridBagLayout.

```
SettingsManagerTab.panelForTweet1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
this.add(SettingsManagerTab.panelForTweet1);

SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetPhoto1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
        SettingsManagerTab.class.getResource("/res/User1.png")));

final GridBagConstraints a = new GridBagConstraints(), b = new GridBagConstraints(), c = new GridBagConstraints(), d = new GridBagConstraints();
a.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
a.gridx = 0;
a.weightx = 0.1;
a.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
SettingsManagerTab.panelForTweet1.add(SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetPhoto1, a);

SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetUsername1 = new JLabel("@usuario1");
final Font contentFont = new Font(SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetUsername1.getFont()
        .getName(), Font.BOLD, SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetUsername1.getFont()
        .getSize());
final Font userFont = new Font(contentFont.getName(), Font.BOLD,
        (int) (contentFont.getSize() * 0.7));
SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetUsername1.setFont(userFont);
b.weightx = 1;
b.gridwidth = 2;
b.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
SettingsManagerTab.panelForTweet1.add(SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetUsername1, b);

SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetContent1 = new JLabel("contenido");
SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetContent1.setFont(contentFont);
c.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
c.weightx = 1;
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
SettingsManagerTab.panelForTweet1.add(SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetContent1, c);

SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetHashtag1 = new JLabel("#demo");
SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetHashtag1.setFont(contentFont);
d.weightx = 30;
d.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
SettingsManagerTab.panelForTweet1.add(SettingsManagerTab.labelForTweetHashtag1, d);
```